# Get data from pg_query

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I'm facing a problem:

Here's the code:

```
/* connection */
$gaSql['user']       = $dbuname;
$gaSql['password']   = $dbpass;
$gaSql['db']         = $dbname;
$gaSql['server']     = $dbhost;

$gaSql['link'] = pg_connect(
    " host=".$gaSql['server'].
    " dbname=".$gaSql['db'].
    " user=".$gaSql['user'].
    " password=".$gaSql['password']
) or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


/* query */
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM person";

$rResult = pg_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ) or die(pg_last_error());

$iTotal = pg_num_rows($rResult);

while ( $aRow = pg_fetch_array($rResult, null, PGSQL_ASSOC) ) {
    //do something...
}
```

My problem is:

Assumed table `person` have total 10 rows. The variable `$iTotal` returned the correct number of rows: 10. **But**, when I try to fetch it using `pg_fetch_array`, it cannot fetch (it didn't enter the `while` operation).

What's wrong with this situation? Please, can anyone help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: IMHO, everything seems right. What's the content of the loop ?

Comment: You could enable php error. It may be useful.

Comment: @AdrienLeber: get data. e.g.: `$name = $aRow['name'];`. How to enabled it??

Comment: [enable php error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). Can you try `print_r($aRow);`

Comment: I can't. Because it didn't enter the loop.

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue, your code works well. http://pastebin.com/ecJvbE8h

Comment: @JazZ: okay.. thank you :)